# Is there a way to send emails with google scripts (sheets) not from gmail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With google scripts you can send emails from your drive spreadsheets, which works pretty neat.

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

But I want to send email from my own emailadres using my own smtp .
Is there a way to send email from google scripts, what don't come from your gmail address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your email address as an alias in your Gmail account. You can then specify the alias in the sendEmail function as shown in this snippet:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {
                        from: "alias@example.com",
                        name: "Sender's Name"
});
```

Comment: When was the last time this was tested? This is not working for me. Despite having set up an alias (it is even set as the default send address) it still sends from the gmail address. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @luciusdegeer I don't know when it changed but as of July 2021, one has to use the GmailApp API to use the "from" option with Gmail aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an external email provider that allows you to POST to their API. Then you can use [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) to do that posting.

Something like:

```js
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/email';
const FROM_ADDRESS = 'from@example.com';
const API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN';

let emailAddress = 'to@example.com';

let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  API_ENDPOINT,
  {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Basic: ${API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'From': FROM_ADDRESS,
      'To': emailAddress,
      'Subject': 'POSTing email from Google Scripts',
      'TextBody': 'You have succesfully POSTed email Google Scripts',
    })
  }
);
console.log(response.getContentText());
```